# WP7 Silverlight - How to navigate from app to core OS page - Eg. Mobile Network

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, navigation

This is probably something simple, but I can't seem to find the answer.

I want to have a button on an app that navigates to a core OS page, eg.. Email setup, or Mobile network.

I assume it is a variation of below, but I im not sure what the format would be for accessing a page on the os from the app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(
            String.Format("/PageName.xaml)), 
            UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, there's no way to access every OS page, such as the Mobile Network page. However, there are some [Launchers and Choosers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769550%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) you can use. That MSDN link is for 7.1 (Mango) so not all Launchers and Choosers mentioned there will be available if you're targetting 7.0. Is there anything in particular you're trying to achieve? There may be an alternate method available.

Comment: thanks for the reseponse. I am basically just trying to cut out a few steps when changing settings, as there is no API for a number of things, Bluetoot, 3G, Data etc..

Comment: No, unfortunately there's no way to have your app jump to those settings pages at the moment.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. There seems to be some very basic elements that are missing from wp7 API's. Hopefully these will be added in the future.